# How to color Text in Popup menu of NSComboBox?

Tags: cocoa, user-controls, user-interface

I'm using a NSComboBox and want to mark some of the items in the popup list appear in red.
I couldn't find a proper Method to override in NSComboBoxCell. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the popup button's menu items directly, but it's not very hard. You shouldn't even need to subclass, you can do it all from the controller.

```
NSMenu *menu = [popUpButton menu];
NSMenuItem *item = [menu itemWithTag:100];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[item title] attributes:attributes];

[item setAttributedTitle:string];
```

You'll probably want to copy attributes from the existing attributed string title so the font and size remain the same, but that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately an NSComboBox does not have a menu. NSPopUpButton has a menu. Actually I'm using only the NSComboBoxCell in a NSTableView.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `NSCell`'s `-setAttributedStringValue:` method? Just create an `NSAttributedString` which has the color you want set for the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` key and you should be good to go.

Comment: This would change the color of the current displayed text. I want to set a different color then black to strings in the popup menu list that appears when you click the triangles. I want to highlight some values in the list. In my use case I want to highlight recommended values the user should select from the popup list.